# Windows 10 UWP Desktop Bridge Application (C++): VCLibs dependencies in a debug build

Tags: c++, uwp, desktop-bridge

I am developing a Windows 10 UWP App with a desktop bridge writen in C++
 (Compiled with /ZW).
The executable has a dependency to the Visual C++ Runtime.

- When I add the dependency

`<PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop" MinVersion="14.0.24123.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />`

to the application's manifest in a release build all works fine. I install the application side-loaded. (MinVersion is the version of the VCLibs package copied into the "Dependencies" output folder during the build)

- When I add the dependency

`<PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug.UWPDesktop" MinVersion="14.0.25022.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />`

to the application's manifest in a debug build (as documented here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/07/07/using-visual-c-runtime-in-centennial-project/, see "For Debugging"), I cannot install the package with the error "Windows cannot install package ... because this package depends on a framework that could not be found. Provide the framework "Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug.UWPDesktop" published by ...".

- When I skip adding the dependency at all I can install the application, but as expected the desktop bridge process fails to start with the error "vccorlib140.DLL was not found" (or vccorlib140d.DLL in case of a debug build).
  However, manually installing the Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug packages from the build output "Dependencies" folder does not change anything.
- When I add the dependency (without the UWPDesktop suffix)

`<PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug" MinVersion="14.0.25022.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />`

to the application's manifest in a debug build, I can install the application, but it also fails launching with "vccorlib140d.DLL was not found".

How do I get the debug build working?
Of course I can copy the VCLibs-DLLs into the system's System32 directory which works but it would be nice if a debug build also works "out of the box".

I am using a 64-Bit Windows 10 Enterprise version 15063.540.

Regards,
Dominik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to test the debug version you will need to install the debug VCLIB appx package manually first. More info can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/cpp/c-runtime-packages-desktop-bridge

Comment: Thank you for your answere!
This worked.
The build output only copies the "Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.Debug.14.00" package, but not the "Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop" package, which seem to be different.
When installing the second one, it works.

Comment: I got a little confused with the differend suffixes "UWPDesktop", "Desktop", "Debug" ...

Do you know why when building the procject with MSBuild the desktop VCLibs are not copied into the dependencies output folder although stated in the manifest?

Comment: Neither one is actually packaged with the appx. The way dependent framework packages work is that they come from the Store to avoid having each app package the same thing. However, the debug VCLib packages are not in the Store, so for testing in debug via sideloading you have to install them manually.

Comment: And what about the "Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.Debug.14.00"/"Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00" package which is copied into the "Dependencies" output folder when doing a MsBuild? For what is this? UWP only? When running the "Add-AppDevPackage.ps1" power shell script which is generated by the build is executed it explicitly installs this dependency. Even in a debug build.

Comment: Yes, the developer script does this. It installs the local framework package. It doesn't pull it from the Store. If you were to double-click the appx package on a machine with VS installed, it wouldn't be able to find the dependency. Maybe your feedback is that this script could be enlightened to also be aware of the DesktopBridge flavor of the libs?

Comment: Yes, I would expect MSBuild to copy both and the "Add-AppDevPackage.ps1" script to install both the "Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.Debug.14.00" and the "Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.Debug.14.00.Desktop" package ("Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00"/"Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop" for release) if the package has a DesktopBridge and stated a dependency to the UWPDesktop-VCLibs.

Comment: I think it's a reasonable expectation. I will convey this to the VS team. Not all parts of the UWP project system have been enlightened yet about the Desktop Bridge.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be ARM64 debug packages available, do you know where I can download those?

Comment: This link is dead. I'm also interested in ARM64 debug packages.

Comment: @Chris Anderson Thanks - updated with a link to more comprehensive info

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT if I understand correctly those VCLibs are downloaded automatically from the store during app installation ? Is that correct ?   How come I cannot find them in the store ? are they hidden or something ? I  search for "VCLibs"

Comment: Yes, they are hidden in the store front. They are not products that users install individually, they framework packages that support other products.