# Declared package dependency unavailable while uploading uwp package to windows app store

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10-universal, desktop-bridge

When I upload the appxbundle, windows app store is giving error like :

**Declared package dependency unavailable: Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop, Neutral, Universal,Universal**

I have included the package dependency in the Package.appxmanifest file :
Below is the code :

```
<Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14393.0" />
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop" MinVersion="14.0.27323.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
  </Dependencies>
```

This dependency is the retail version.

**Do I need to do anything else for including this dependency ?**

Comment: Why you need add this  `PackageDependency` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 UWP Desktop Bridge Application (C++): VCLibs dependencies in a debug build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117471/windows-10-uwp-desktop-bridge-application-c-vclibs-dependencies-in-a-debug)

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT My app requires vc++ runtime dependency to be installed on target system. So I included this PackageDependency.  I included the retail version of the dependency so that while installing the app first dependencies will get installed and then app. Store should automatically download the dependency. Acutally If am running the app then dependency is getting installed fine. The only problem is I am getting this error when I upload the app on Store. Microsoft store is not accepting this package because of this dependency.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Below link describes how to add the dependency :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-prepare

Comment: To submit app to Partner Center, using the app package upload file(.msixupload or .appxupload) is a better choose. You could refer to [Create your app package upload file using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#create-your-app-package-upload-file-using-visual-studio) to create your package. By the way, please check the Compile with **.NET Native tool chain**  before you create your package and choose Release mode in Solution Configuration on Select and Configure Packages Step.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I have created the app using visual studio only and the extension is .appxupload only. Also Project configuration is in release mode. Also I have performed the windows certification kit and the overall result is passed.

Comment: Could you try to set the min and target with high version?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT The problem is in PackageDependency only. If I am removing the PackageDependency from the package.appxmanifest file and then uploading the package then it is getting uploaded on the store.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I tried setting the min and target version  but still getting the same error while uploading the package.
`<Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.18362.0" />
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.18362.0" />
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop" MinVersion="14.0.27323.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
  </Dependencies>`

Comment: Well, I will report this issue.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Please report it ASAP. I am stuck with the uploading of package.
Can you please verify once of having this dependency in the package and then uploading to the store. Is it like this dependency should be installed on the developer machine ?

Comment: I recently uploaded a package with the following dependecy without any problem (note the min version): <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop" MinVersion="14.0.24217.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz : I copied the same line. But still I am not able to upload the package. Getting the same error "Declared package dependency unavailable: Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop, Neutral, Universal,Universal"

Do I need to place the appx file present in the retail folder to my package ? Or by just mentioning the name, minversion and publisher in the manifest file is enough ?

Comment: Can you share your AppxManifest.xml file? It doesn't matter where the appx file is when you uplaod it AFAIK.

Comment: I saw that you have already sloved your issue from this thread( https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/1098/declared-package-dependency-unavailable-microsoftv.html). Could you please summary your solution in to the answer part, in this way it will help the other community member who meets the same issues as you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved now. Let me summarize the solution for those who might face the same issue.
Since VC++ runtime libraries can't be neutral so the project configuration should be either x86 or x64 or both while creating the appxbundle. VC++ libraries won't work with AnyCpu Architecture.